# Apos a formatação a data aparece com 3 horas a mais

Tags: swift, data

mais cedo tive problema ao transformar uma String em date, com muito custo consegui colocar na hora exata, mas agora quando fui gerar as notificação a bendita data aparece com algumas horas a mais, fiz de tudo que imaginei que pudesse ser mas não consigo a solução

```
 {...
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    let date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr4)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

    if let unwrappedDate = date2 {
        print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(unwrappedDate)) //26/09/2016 21:23
        criaNotificacoes(unwrappedDate, comIntervalo: util.valorIntervalo(campoIntervalo.text!), totalDias: util.valorTempoDias(campoPeriodo.text!))
    }else{
        print("tratar")
    }


}
func criaNotificacoes(dataInicio: NSDate, comIntervalo intervalo:Int, totalDias qtdDias:Int){
    print("data de inicio recebida --->",dataInicio)//2016-09-27 00:23:00
    let dateComponentes = NSDateComponents()
    let calendario = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    calendario.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    calendario.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dateComponentes.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

    var fireDate: NSDate = NSDate()
    fireDate.descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())

      fireDate = calendario.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponentes, toDate: dataInicio, options: NSCalendarOptions())!

    print(fireDate,"data inicio")//2016-09-27 00:23:00
}
```

Comment: Você está testando no simulador ou em um dispositivo real? Se for no simulador é possível que ele esteja com outro fuso horário. Neste caso, basta ir nos Ajustes e ajustar o fuso.

Comment: Isso no proprio iphone :/

Comment: NSDate não possui timezone, é sempre GMT, o que muda é o posicionamento do usuário no planeta (timezone). Sempre que você print na NSDate você ta vendo a data com 3 horas a mais por que aqui é GMT -3. O DateFormatter por default usa local time zone, basta você usar o método stringFromDate do DateFormatter pra ver a hora local (default) ou se você quiser voce pode mudar o timezone do DateFormatter e mostrar a hora de outro local.